# How to remove site name in title in Google Analytics 4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

The title tags of my pages have this format:

```
The title — The site name
```

I want Google Analytics 4 to trim the  `— The site name` part at the end. Is there a way to do so? It used to work in UA though:

[image]